# <a> used together with line-through as class does not show line

Tags: html, css

Im using a class to replace deprecated strike in HTML:

```
.entfall { text-decoration : line-through;}
```

Using firefox 38.x and the code

```
<span class="entfall"><a href="some link">text</a></span>
```

the line-through is not shown on the screen.

In fact I would like to use the following:

```
<span class="entfall"><code><a href="some link">text</a></code></span>
```

but the problem seems to happen "earlier".

Is there an explanation? Or are there workarounds possible?

Comment: try this css `.entfall a{ text-decoration : line-through;}`

Comment: Do you have any styles specified for `a` which could override what you've set on the span?

Comment: Both examples show on the screen for me.

Comment: -- remark deleted --

Comment: As @timothyclifford has already mentioned in above comment, my bet is that you have elsewhere a bit of CSS that says something along the lines of: `a { text-decoration: none; }` that is overriding your new style. The comment from @GauravAggarwal is the correct one to use.

Comment: Gaurav Aggarwal: Thanks for your replay. I've tried to extend css but it does not work. Even working line throughs which I have in my HTML disappear. Only putting my    `.entfall { text-decoration : line-through;}`   and your    `.entfall a{ text-decoration : line-through;}`   in the css the others are striked (but the linked ones not).

Comment: I've checked carefully fonts.css, but there is no definition for `<a>`. I'm going to check my files.

Comment: @timothyclifford: I've checked carefully htm-files and css-file. There is no overriding of  `<a>`.

Comment: @Peter if you're issue is in Firefox, can you inspect the element and see what styles are being applied? This should tell you where the issue is coming from. This is how you inspect styles https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_and_edit_CSS

Comment: @timothyclifford sorry reading your comment only now. I'm going to leave the office (after taking the solution I described below and delivering my html-pages just by time). The next time in office I'll try to reconstruct the situation and report it. But don't expect a result before Monday. Thx for your patience, Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling firefox finally solved the problem. Thx to all for your kind support.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've posted already looks fine and works well in Chrome and the latest Firefox using the snippet below. I would check other styles within your stylesheet to make sure they're not overriding it.

Find a link that should be styled and use the developer console to find out what styles are being applied to it on the computed styles.

- right click a link and choose `Inspect Element`
- on the right panel choose the `Computed` tab
- filter on text-decoration

You could also apply the class to the link itself to increase the specificity of the rule, or failing that change it to `.entfall>code>a {...`

```css
.entfall {
  text-decoration : line-through;
}
```

```html
<span class="entfall"><code><a href="some link">strike through text</a></code></span>
```

Comment: He says the problem is in Firefox. I don't see the problem myself.

Comment: Yeah, I wrote it whilst I was getting firefox to check as I was pretty sure it wouldn't be a firefox issue.

Comment: Using Inspector in Firefox I'm receiving the following: `font family > monospace` and `font-size > 12px` (sorry for neglecting line breaks). Nothing else. Hmmmh, perhaps its a feature and not a bug? underline from link and strike from css-class would perhaps not give a nice outcome.

Comment: Folks, I don't want you to waste more time: I'm going to overcome the problem by `<span class="entfall"><code>text</code></span> (<a href="some link">Link</a>)`. The comment from Gaurav Aggarwal ("but in some versions not") is a strong argument to do that. To all: Many thanks four your support.

Answer (score 0):

This is working in some browsers but in some version its not

Use this

```
.entfall a{
  text-decoration : line-through;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.entfall a { 
    text-decoration : line-through;
}
```

If is there any css you have written for anchor tag then `text-decoration: line-through;` will not work you will have to increase the priority of span  `entfall` by either you can give an id to the span i.e. `<span id="entfall-anchor">` and apply the following css on id rather then class because `id` has more weight then `class` or simply you can add '!important' into your css i.e.

`.entfall a { 
    text-decoration : line-through !important;
 }`